# NodeJS-Electron-msnodesqlv8 - Error while loading binaries in msnodesqlv8

Tags: node.js, electron

**Context**: I am building an electron app, which is querying a sql server (remote server) to get the data from table. I am using mssqlnodev8.

**Error**: When I start the electron app using npm start, I get the below error -

> Uncaught Error: None of the binaries loaded successfully. Is your node
>   version either latest 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9 ?
>       at failIfNoBinaryExported (C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:63)
>       at Object.liveLoad (C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:50)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:79)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:81)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658)

**Additional information about electron app -** 
I am using bootstrap for my UI. As per electron faq site, I have the below code in my entry html file

```
<script>
  window.nodeRequire = require;
  delete window.require;
  delete window.exports;
  delete window.module;
</script>
```

All the modules except electron (index.js - entry point) is imported with

> nodeRequire

**Analysis done till now -**

1. The javascript logic to connect to database and fetch records are in
   separate js file. When I execute the file with 'node file.js', it
   works perfectly fine and returns records.
2. The node version is v9.8.0. Electron version is 3.0.2
3. I analyzed bootstrap.js file in node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js, line number 63. It traced to below code

   ```
   var files = require('fs').readdirSync(binaryDir)
   ```

   I changed that too nodeRequire, but it didnt work.
4. I have checked similar issues in github but none of the resolutions helped.

**UPDATED**
I analyzed the bootstrap.js in msnodesqlv8. These are the different error messages

> Error while exporting binary Error:
>   \?\C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bin\sqlserverv8.electron.v2.0.4.ia32.node
>   is not a valid Win32 application.
>   \?\C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bin\sqlserverv8.electron.v2.0.4.ia32.node
>       at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:740)
>       at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20)
>       at attemptToExportBinary (C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:58)
>       at C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:48
>
> Error while exporting binary Error: The module
>   '\?\C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bin\sqlserverv8.electron.v2.0.4.x64.node'
>   was compiled against a different Node.js version using
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the
>   module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
>       at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:740)
>       at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20)
>       at attemptToExportBinary (C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:58)
>       at C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:48
>
> Error while exporting binary Error:
>   \?\C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bin\sqlserverv8.node.v10.8.0.ia32.node
>   is not a valid Win32 application.
>   \?\C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bin\sqlserverv8.node.v10.8.0.ia32.node
>       at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:740)
>       at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20)
>       at attemptToExportBinary (C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:58)
>       at C:\Users\t9sau2\Documents\NodeJs\Renewalverification\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\bootstrap.js:48

Answer (score 1):

I had raised this issue in github report of msnodesqlv8. The owner updated the version, which resolved the issue. github link  - https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/issues/80